# MS-Access Database will not export into email with proper form name

Tags: email, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-forms

I am working on a Database in MS Access. The database has multiple forms within it. Currently, I have an action button that saves the open form as a PDF and attaches it in an email (email has auto-populated "to" line and "subject" line). Many of the forms in this DB need to be saved as PDF and sent via email.

The PDF attaches and the email opens properly, however, the PDF filename is not titled properly. It has a name from another form's attach button function (same email-sending button type, different form).

I did a little digging, and I noticed that when I change the view type to "Design View", the proper title appears:

[image: Design View - Correct Title].

When I am in any other view, it shows the incorrect title:

[image: Form View - Incorrect Title]

I've attached the email view where the PDF attached *should* say **Scrap at TRM**.

[image: Email View]

I've also attached the macro that the button runs:

[image: Macro - button action]

Comment: In your design view , Right click on a blank area on the form . Blank area so as to avoid accidentally clicking an object on your form. Look through every available property, is there one that still says `Ship to TRM`? Which is it? Try and let everyone know if that fixed it.

Comment: Adjust the form's caption property. That will fix it.

Comment: that fixed it!! Thank you guys so much!!!